# I can't install react locally by using this command "npx create-react-app"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

So, I want to start a react project and I run `npx create-react-app myapp` and I get this.

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

I updated the package, I uninstalled it and reinstalled it locally, and I get the same error.

NPM and Node are updated too.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this because of the npm create react app v5 update.

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `create-react-app my-app`

You do not need to install it globally.

Answer (score 0):

npx comes with npm 5.2+. You are currently using the older version. Try the following code:-

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
   This removes an already installed one.
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`
   This is for re-installing
3. `create-react-app my-app`